# Jquery authentication error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, basic-authentication

Consider the following code:

```
var jsonData1 = $.ajax({

      url: 'http://'+domainName+':9898/jolokia/read/*',
      dataType:"json",
      crossDomain: true,
      beforeSend: function(xhr){
          var username= '*';
          var password= '*';
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));

        },
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  var parsed1 = JSON.parse(jsonData1);
```

Here when I directly access the url, it asks for a username and password, which when given shows the value. 
But when I do it through an ajax call, it throws this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
jquery.min.js:5 XMLHttpRequest cannot load     http://10.91.240.21:9898/jolokia/read/* No     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
 (index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

**TRY 2:**

```
      var jsonData2 = $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
      url: 'http://'+domainName+':9898/jolokia/read/*',
      dataType:"jsonp",
      crossDomain: true,
      data: {username: '*',password: '*'},
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  var parsed2 = JSON.parse(jsonData2);
```

I tried using json p.
The unauthorized code got resolved. It is showing status OK. But now this error comes

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: @Cheery I am using the beforeSend argument.

Comment: Look at the second answer by the link. Modern jQuery has attributes for username and password. Or, at least, attribute headers

Comment: @Cheery That ain't working too.

Comment: Then press F12 in the browser, check how data is sent. Compare to what your browser is sending directly.

Comment: @Cheery[link](http://imgur.com/LjD7MqY) Here is what my response on the browser is.

Comment: I was talking about browser's request to the URL under question and then the same request by jQuery. You can select the line with request and at the right side browser will show all the headers of the request.

Comment: @Cheery Under which tab will I be able to view this data.

Comment: @Cheery [link](http://imgur.com/qRpUjuY) Here is the response tab.

Comment: @Cheery I used jsonp and updated the question, Please have a look.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the answer. The cross domain issue is resolved.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var surl = "http://www.anotherdomain.com/webservice.asmx";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: surl,
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { UserID: 1234 },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            async: false,
            cache: false
         });
         });
```